# locking the Iphone screen with phone Gap

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I wanted to know if the phone gap allows you to lock the screen to one position and not change it's resolution when the user is turning his iphone/android device?

I'm Developing an app that is based on HTML/JS and don't want to build my UI Again when the user is turning his phone from side to side

Just To make Clear - I'm working inside the device browser with HTML/JS/Jquery

is it possible?

p.s my intention is presenting the app in portarit position

Answer (score 0):

On manifest file, where you have the activities list, on activity node you should add:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" ...../>
```

or

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" ...../>
```

depends on what you need.

Comment: I'm working inside the device browser with HTML/JS/Jquery, and not from eclipse/mac

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation for your app in xcode for iPhone:

[image]

or in your android manifest file with:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" .../>
```

or

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" .../>
```

Comment: This case is not relevant..
I'm writing an app that lives inside a webpage, and the company that i'm working for doesnt uses the XCode and eclipse tools

Comment: why did you add the phonegap tag then?

Comment: because ive been told the phone gap adds abilities to the programmer that he cannot achieved via using only the browser. I wanted to know if through it i can make that happen

Comment: if you are using phonegap you do have a native project per platform so this is relevant. If you are building a pure web app inside the browser you can not lock the orientation